# Programatically checking for NSBundle in macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cmake

I am building my application for macOS using CMake. My application can either be  MACOSX_BUNDLE i.e. generated as a `.app` through CMake or it can even be a Unix-style executable.
Is there a programmatic way in Obj-C to check if the executable is **Unix-Style** or **NSBundle**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use `Foundation` and Objective-C in both binaries it is possible to check using `NSBundle` properties, because bundle instance itself will created on both cases (it just references to folder around executing binary), but bundle info will be present only on macOS.

So here is possible approach:

```
if (nil != [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]) {
// macOS code here
} else {
// linux code here
}
```